# client_side_validations gem for third level of multi level nested field_for did not generate validation attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-attributes, client-side-validation

I've got a problem with a multi level nested form on the third level. I've got three models which are involved in my form.

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :years
  validates_presence_of :name
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :years
end

class Year < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :year_contacts
  validates_presence_of :year_name
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :year_contacts
end

class YearContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :year
  validates_presence_of :contact_name
end
```

This is my form:

```
<%= form_for @school, :validate => true do |f| %>
  <h4>School</h4>
  <%= f.label 'Name', :class => 'control-label' %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'span12', :placeholder => "School name"  %>
  <h4>Year of Graduating</h4>
  <%= f.fields_for :years do |fo| %>
    <%= fo.label 'Year' %>
    <%= fo.text_field :year_name  %>
    <h4>Contact</h4>
    <%= fo.fields_for :year_contacts do |foo| %>
      <%= foo.label %>
      <%= foo.text_field :contact_name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The client side validation works like a charm for the school attribute and also for the nested year attribute. But when it comes to the third level nesting it didn't work. There isn't any client side validation for the year_contacts attribute.

I'm not sure if it's a bug, a known limitation of client_side_validations or a error on my side. All known Issues I found were only for two models nested under another model but no true multi level structure like mine.

I opened a ticket on github: https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/568

I use Rails 3.2.1 and client_side_validations 3.2.5

The form works well. All data is saved as expected.

Comment: Any success with this?

Comment: Facing the exact issue with multi nested form. Any success??